# @Transactional spring JPA .save() not necessary?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactional-database

I understand that if we use annotation @Transactional. "save()" method is not necessary. Is it exact?

And for my example:

```
@Transactional
void methodA() {
   ...
   ObjectEntity objectEntity = objectRepository.find(); 
   methodB(objectEntity);
}

void methodB(ObjectEntity obj) {
   ...
   obj.setName("toto");
   objectRepository.save(obj);    <-- is it necessary?
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In this particular case (when operating existing entity within same Session) it's not necessary, since `@Transactional` under the hood saves and flushes all changes to managed entities to DB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works like following:

- `save()` attaches the entity to the session and at the end of the transaction as long as there were no exceptions it will all be persisted to the database.
- Now if you get the object from the DB (e.g. `ObjectEntity objectEntity = objectRepository.find();`) then **that object is already attached and you don't need to call the save() method**.
- If the object, however, is detached (e.g. `ObjectEntity objectEntity = new ObjectEntity();`) then **you must use the save() method** in order to attach it to the session so that changes made to it are persisted to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

*[It is a little too late, but I hope it would be helpful to future readers]*:

Within a transaction context, an update to a managed instance is reflected in the persistence storage at the commit/flush time, i.e., in your case at the end of `methodB()`. However, calling `save()` comes with a cost in scenarios like yours, as stated in [Spring Boot Persistence Best Practices](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Anghel-Leonard/dp/1484256255):

> The presence or absence of save() doesn’t affect the number or type of
> queries, but it still has a performance penalty, because the save()
> method fires a MergeEvent behind the scenes, which will execute a
> bunch of Hibernate-specific internal operations that are useless in
> this case. So, in scenarios such as these, avoid the explicit call of
> the save() method.